# In Dataframes getting error "importError: Missing optional dependency 'lxml'. Use pip or conda to install lxml"

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here is the Program:

here is the error message:
In Dataframes getting error "import Error: Missing optional dependency 'lxml'.  Use pip or conda to install lxml"

what pip installation needs to be done? I did upgrade also still getting the error

Comment: `pip install lxml` or `conda install lxml`?

Comment: Try `pip install pandas[xml]` which will install `lxml` automatically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.